# Message not sending because of a "BAD REQUEST" with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, python-asyncio, discord.py

I'm making a bot with Discord.py and I keep getting an error when trying to send a message with an embed.

Here's the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\Documents\Storage\python\NanoBot\bot.py", line 101, in on_message
    await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 1152, in send_message
data = yield from self.http.send_message(channel_id, content, guild_id=guild_id, tts=tts, embed=embed)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 198, in request
raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400)
```

My code:

```
embed = discord.Embed(color=target.color)
embed.set_thumbnail(url=target.avatar_url)
embed.set_author(name=str(target.name), url="Playing " + str(target.game))
embed.set_footer(text="!!userinfo command")
embed.add_field(name="Status", value=str(target.status))
embed.add_field(name="Nickname", value=str(target.nick))
embed.add_field(name="Account Created", value=str(target.created_at))
embed.add_field(name="Roles", value=str(roles))
embed.add_field(name="Joined at", value=str(target.joined_at))
await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)
```

Comment: You could add a few print statements into `C:\Users\pc\Documents\Storage\python\NanoBot\bot.py` and check the values that are being passed as `message.chanel` and `embed`.. if you are sure those values are correct google for `http 400 errors` to find [pages like this one](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E400.html) that might help you to better understand what might be going wrong..

Comment: If this doesn't help, see if you can add the code of your bot. Re-write into a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example and edit/update your question.

Comment: @SB87 I added the code that I'm using for the program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're using discord api, if you read the description of `client.send_message`, if you send a message in the `embed` is longer than 2000 chrs, discord will raise a 400 request error. For Discord's character limit is 2000.

As you can see, it's not actually a real error, `discord.errors.HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400)`. It's a custom error made by discord API. To correct it, you can split the message into embeds that has less than 2000 chrs and send them separately. To be clear, this **isn't** because that the server is down, but because the server rejected to send your message since it's too long.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Removing some of the `field`s worked.

Comment: @Nanomotion for future reference, these are the limits for embeds: Number of fields = 25, field name = 256, value = 1024, description = 2048.