# Requesting a dictionary definition python | Discord bot

Tags: python, python-requests, discord.py

So I am trying to request a definition from oxford dictionary through their API and when the user type !define (users word) the bot returns the definition. I am having a few issues see the code below.

```
@client.command()
async def define(word_id):

app_id = '************'
app_key = '***********'

language = 'en'

url = 'https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/entries/' + 
language + '/' + word_id.lower()

r = requests.get(url, headers={'app_id': app_id, 'app_key': app_key})

await client.say("The definition is " + ("text \n" + r.text))
```

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
discord.errors.HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400) + discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400)
```

Here is what they expect me to use:

```
import requests
import json

# TODO: replace with your own app_id and app_key
app_id = '****'
app_key = '******'

language = 'en'
word_id = 'Ace'

url = 'https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/entries/' + 
language + '/' + word_id.lower()

r = requests.get(url, headers = {'app_id': app_id, 'app_key': 
app_key})

print("code {}\n".format(r.status_code))
print("text \n" + r.text)
print("json \n" + json.dumps(r.json()))
```

Comment: What exactly are the issues you're facing?  Could you fix the indentation of the code here?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yes I am getting discord.errors.HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400) + discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400)

Comment: The API is rejecting your request as malformed in some way.  Do you have access  to any documentation for the endpoints as to what they expect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error 400 in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43016830/error-400-in-discord-py)

Comment: I will add their example to the original @PatrickHaugh

Comment: Could you also include the full error traceback?  I thought that the `requests` line was failing, but it looks like it might be the `send_message` instead.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh discord.errors.HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400) do you think that the response is too long for discord? This is the successful response [link]https://pastebin.com/S3KZhEqV