# discord.py/PIL sending image/gif files error 50006

Tags: python, discord.py, python-imaging-library

I'm dealing with some image/gif files on discord.py plus PIL but sometimes when I try to send an image/gif from a file it gives me this error:

```
Ignoring exception in command battle:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "./discordbot.py", line 1487, in battle
    await battlevs(ctx, int(o))
  File "./discordbot.py", line 1838, in battlevs
    await ctx.send(file=file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 1047, in send
    message_reference=reference)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 254, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message
```

(The file is sent in a function called battlevs)
My source code is like 200 lines long so I won't post it here unless really needed. Please help.

Comment: PLZ add the error line

Comment: Plese, check if https://stackoverflow.com/a/43016983/206413 solves your problem:  if you send a message in the embed is longer than 2000 chrs, discord will raise a 400 request error. For Discord's character limit is 2000.

Comment: @Delta I edited the post. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @MarcusViniciusPompeu My embed definitely doesn't have over 2000 characters.

Comment: can I see value of variable "file"?

Comment: @Delta When I print out "file" it returns ```<discord.file.File object at 0x7f0628c9c2b0>```

Comment: I think your code is correct and the's bug is related to the package.

Comment: Try updating discord.py. Your code seems entirely correct.

Comment: @Makonede how do u update discord.py?

Comment: @bobasdf `pip install -U discord.py`